# sed replace a newline and a literal with literal?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Im trying to replace this text with this command but it doesn't work:

```
sed -e 's/\nnumber2/number2/g'  fffff > fffff
```

This is what my file contains:

```
number1;gAMMA
number2;gat
number1;zilla
number2;dog
```

This is my expected output:

```
number1;gAMMAnumber2;gat
number1;zillanumber2;dog
```

Comment: number1;gAMMAnumber2;gat
number1;zillanumber2;dog

Comment: number1;gAMMAnumber2;gat /n 
number1;zillanumber2;dog

Comment: i put in the question at the end

Comment: The problems are: (1) Do not read and redirect to the same file. You have to write to another file to be safe. (2) `sed` only reads one line at a time, so you cannot replace newlines. [There is a hack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26290/187122) but I would recommend `perl` instead. (3) You may have to write `$'...\n...'` instead of `...\n...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nnumber2/number2/g' fffff > fffff
```

[here is the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^number2/ {n=1} 
       {printf "%s"(n?"\n":""), $0; n=0}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

or perhaps set `ORS` and use `print`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments already, Perl would probably be better suited for this multiline task:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(number1[^\n]*)\n/\1/' yourfile.txt
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this with Perl, but this is fairly straight forward. It will also create a backup file with `.bak` extension, if you don't want that, omit the `bak` part.